# Do women need to cover their hair if they have had children without being married?

Tags: halacha, children-parenting, pregnancy-birth, hair-covering

Do women need to cover their hair if they have had children without being married?

Some explanations for hair covering relate it to modesty in light of the supposed attractive power of hair, which would imply that she only needs to cover it if she is actually married to someone (or has been married and therefore obliged to cover).

However, other explanations have to do with virginity and/or public presumptions of virginity. According to these, one imagines any woman with children would have to cover.

Finally, there may be a concern in this case of ma'arit ha-ayin for not covering.

Comment: Can you source either or these?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11388/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34541/759

Comment: Yes, most certainly. I'm on the road though. Will add in a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from the Tiztz Eliezer that one would not be required(However,see the Shevus Yaakov).

שו"ת ציץ אליעזר חלק טו סימן נה ד"ה הנה הא

הנה הא גם בספרי שם הא כתוב דמההיא דשמואל אין ראיה לדבר כי אם זכר לדבר בלבד, ויעוין בספרי דבי רב שם שמבאר שלהכי הוא רק זכר לדבר בלבד, כי י"ל דמה ששמה ידה על ראשה לא היה זה אלא דרך צער ויגון ממה שאירע לה עם אחיה, ע"ש, ויתר על כן ראיתי בפי' כתר כהונה על הספרי שמבאר, דמה שאמרו זכר לדבר לפי שמשורת הדין לא היתה תמר נצרכת לאותו דבר שבבעולה שלא בנשואין כשנבעלת בזנות ליכא בה איסור פריעת ראש מן התורה לדעת כמה מהפוסקים בלתי דעת השבו"י ועוד מהאחרונים שפסקו לאסור אף באנוסה ואין דבריהם מוכרעים לדינא עיין שם.

ואמנם בשו"ת שבות יעקב ח"א סי' ק"ג מביא באמת הוכחה לאיסור אפילו בבעולה מזנות מההיא דתמר שהספרי לומד משם לכיסוי ראשן כדיעו"ש. אבל מדהש"ס דילן לא הביא מזה י"ל דהוא משום דסבירא ליה כנז' דבאנוסה אין איסור, וזה שתמר שמה ידה על ראשה היה זה משום צער ויגון בלבד וכנ"ל, ואפי' לפי הספרי ג"כ י"ל שאין המכוון בהרמז כי אם על הנשואות וכפי שראיתי בספר ערך שי על אה"ע סי' כ"א שכותב לבאר (דלא כהשבו"י) דהזכר לדבר הוא על נשואה, (ועפ"י הפ"מ ח"א סי' ל"ה), מפני דתינח אם נשואה אינה הולכת בגילוי ראש יסברו שהיא נשואה (ולא יוודע שזנתה), לכן מדתמר כסתה ראשה כדרך האנוסות שמכסין ראשם כדי שיסברו שהיא נשואה יש זכר לדבר דנשואה לא תלך בגילוי ראש עיין שם, ואכ"מ להאריך עוד.

There is more on this discussion with a lot of material that seems to come out with the same conclusion but inserts opinions which disagree.see here for more.

פתחי תשובה על שולחן ערוך אבן העזר הלכות אישות סימן כא סעיף ב

Answer (score 2):

There are two halachic concepts -- hair as *erva*, and a married woman's obligation to cover. If hair is *erva*, why is uncovering okay before a woman gets married? Numerous poskim (Ben Ish Chai, Aruch HaShulchan, Rav Moshe Feinstein) all suggested that this definition of *erva* is subjective, and no one is shocked by a single woman with uncovered hair.

If so, why do poskim prefer (though there's leeway in many situations) that a widow continue to cover her hair? Either that's simply the norm that evolved, or once the obligation to cover kicked in, it remains in effect (or alternatively, the obligation to cover turns it into a sort of *erva*) -- there are mp3s on yutorah where Rabbis Broyde and Willig address this issue.

I've never heard any contemporary posek suggest that non-covering had anything to do with virginity -- and actually, I find that quite offensive.

Many divorcees and widows have heterim to uncover their hair, for job or shidduch reasons. This would *certainly* apply here. But putting that aside -- *if* it could be argued that societal norms treat a "mom's" hair as *erva*, then maybe you could argue that she should cover. I can't think of any other reason why she should cover, though. (Now if all her friends at parent teacher conferences, including the divorced ones, cover their hair, it might be helpful for her to do so too as far as school standards or not sticking out. But I can't see any halachic argument, other than erva vis-a-vis norms.)

Comment: I've never heard any contemporary posek suggest anything about anything whatsoever. However, to the best of my understanding, hair covering depends exactly on virginity. Even a rape victim has to cover, but if the hymen is missing when not a result of relations (*mukas eitz*), no covering is necessary. Why is that offensive to you?

Comment: @NBZ what's your source that a rape victim has to cover? (Don't tell me the mishna in Kesubos about hinuma)

Comment: The Chelkat Mechokek (21:2) says it applies to anyone who is a בעולה. Why is that offensive? Even the Beit Shemuel there contrasts Gerusha/Almana with plain Betulah. It's likely he didn't even consider the case of Beulah+Bachelorette.

Comment: @doubleaa, not so simple ,see the Pischei Tshuva that I bring.