# Does a Jewish woman who was married to a non-Jew and then divorced, need to cover her hair?

Tags: halacha, intermarriage, hair-covering

Does a Jewish woman who was a non-practicing Jew that married a non-Jewish man and had children together, then divorced him and she became Torah observant.... need to cover her hair?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for this oft-relevant question! I recommend our [tour]. The answers at http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/54053 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49279 may answer your question, especially when you bear in mind that marriage to a non-Jew is not considered marriage in the eyes of _halacha_. Note, though, that you should [ask your rabbi](/q/9146) this question if it's practical, relying on this site [only for background information](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: When I divorced I was informed that according to Jewish law, I was never married. But I have two children, so am not sure if that means I should cover my hair.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a Jewish woman married to a non-Jew need to cover her hair?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/54053/does-a-jewish-woman-married-to-a-non-jew-need-to-cover-her-hair)